# set of nth-power elements of a finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and let $H$ be a subset of $G$ defined by for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$H=\{x^{n}\,:\,x\in G\}.$$

I know that the $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$.

So, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of $G$ is divisible by $H$.

Is it possible to compute the order of $H$ if the order of $G$ is given?

(The case what i'm dealing with $|G|=525$ and $n=21$. I wonder if there is a general way to compute the order of $H$.)

Give some advice or any hint. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the Sylow theorems are useful? We know for any $a \in H$ that $|a| \mid 25$ since $525=21 \cdot 25$. This implies that $H$ is a $5$-subgroup of $G$, narrowing down the possible order for $H$ to $\{1,5,25\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using fundamental theorem of abelian groups $G$ should be isomorphic to one of these groups $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7\times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$, $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$. It can be seen that $21=3 \times 7$ does not affect any any element of order $5$ or of order $25$. Therefore if $x\in G$ such that $\mid x \mid =5$ or $25$ then $\mid x^{21} \mid= \mid x\mid$. So $\mid H\mid$ is multiple of $25$. Now if $x\in G$ such that $\mid x \mid=3$ or  $\mid x \mid=7$ then $ x^{21}=(x^{3})^7=(x^7)^3=e$. Therefore the subgroup $H$ only contains elements of order $5$ or of order $25$. Hence order of $H$ is $25$.

Comment: How can you be certain that $H$ contains any elements of order $25$? If every element in $H$ is of order $5$ then $|H|=5$.

Comment: Since $G$ is isomorphic to one of these groups $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7\times \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$, $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_7\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$. I said that if $G$ has any element of order $25$ then it must be in $H$ also. If $G$ does not have any element of order $25$ then of course $H$ can not hyave.

Comment: @Dastur No, $|H|=25$ even if $H$ has only elements of order $5$.

Comment: @MANI Thank you for your comments. It helped a lot for me. But, I have a question. 
If there is no assumption that $G$ is abelian, does it make no sense to discuss the order of $H$ in case of $|G|=525$ with $n=21$?

Comment: @Primavera If $G$ is not abelian then $H$ need not be a subgroup for example conside $G=S_3$ and $H=\{x^3:x\in S_3 \}$ then $H=\{I,(12),(23),(12)(23)\}.$ since $\mid H \mid=4$, it can not become a subgroup of $S_3.$, in your case please do the needful calculation, perhaps it will not form subgroup if $G$ is not abelian.\

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no in general. For example, if $|G|=4$ and $n=2$, then $H$ could have order $1$ or $2$.

In the particular case you are interested in though, it's not too hard to see that $G=G_5\times C_{21}$, where $G_5$ is the Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$. It's then not hard to see that $H=G_5$ (more or less as in MANI's answer, if it was written carefully), so $|H|=25$.

More generally, this argument works whenever $G$ is an abelian group (or even nilpotent), $n$ divides $|G|$ but is coprime to $|G|/n$.

Comment: I have answered for the particular case asked by @Primavera